# ON DELETE CASCADE alternatives and performance (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my program I store entries in a table and an entry may also have child items.

```
id uniqueidentifier not null primary key
parent uniqueidentifier null (another id from the same table or null)
... other columns
```

In this table only top-level entries can have child items, so cycles or recursion are not possible.

If I delete an entry, I want also delete child items. Unfortunately, there is no way to add ON DELETE CASCADE to such table:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '...' on table '...' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

I can, however, just specify an additional condition in my delete statement to do the same:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = @GUID OR parent = @GUID
```

The problem is that parent column is not indexed. This column also has a lot of duplicate values (NULLs) and as I know, duplicate values are very bad when used with indexes. I would like to know, what is the best solution for this problem

1. Is there a better solution to remove both child and parent items?
2. Should I use index on parent column and if yes, what type of index should I use in this case - there are a lot of duplicate values
3. Not sure, but I suggest that OR-statement in the above solution make primary key index useless and SQL server will just scan the entire table.

PS

I cannot create another table to store child items.

Comment: /duplicate values are very bad when used with indexes/  Why do you think that.  If you had a table with Citizens of the USA, and an index on their StateKey (aka CommonwealthKey)..... that would be "bad"?  Select * from dbo.Citizen where StateKey = 33.  (Where 33 represents Virginia for example).  You think it would be better to do a table scan for Virginia over an index?

Comment: I agree with GranadaCoder.  You should index parent column.  If it's not indexed, then you *already* have a problem SELECTing the child items.  I presume SELECTs will happen on the table much more frequently thant DELETEs.